# Qt: CUDA with Qt OSX Yosemite "sed: illegal option -- r" error

Tags: c++, qt, cuda

I am building a simple app with Qt creator, in which I want to utilise CPU and GPU computation to complete a task and then compare the execution time in m/s.

I have read numerous articles and have concluded that I need to separate NVCC and GCC compilers from one another to avoid conflict.   I followed [this tutorial](https://cudaspace.wordpress.com/2012/07/05/qt-creator-cuda-linux-review/), making tweaks for my system, however when I compile I get a strange error:

```
sed: illegal option -- r
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]
make: *** [gaussian_cuda.o] Error 1
14:42:46: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
```

The error is obviously being thrown from this line in my `.pro` configuration:

```
2>&1 | sed -r \"s/\\(([0-9]+)\\)/:\\1/g\" 1>&2
```

I don't understand why this is an illegal operation, and when I try to remove this line my code breaks completely.

Why is `r` an illegal operation?

**EDIT** Complete config code:

```
QT       += core gui
QT       += multimedia
QT       += multimediawidgets
QT       += concurrent

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = WebcamFilter
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
           mainwindow.cpp \
           camerafeed.cpp \

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
            camerafeed.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

# CUDA Resources
CUDA_SOURCES += gaussian.cu
CUDA_DIR      = /usr/local/cuda
# Path to header and lib files
INCLUDEPATH  += $$CUDA_DIR/include
QMAKE_LIBDIR += $$CUDA_DIR/lib
# Libs used for source code
LIBS         += -lcudart -lcuda
# GPU Architecture
CUDA_ARCH     = sm_20
# Custom flags for nvcc
NVCCFLAGS     = --compiler-options -fno-strict-aliasing -use_fast_math --ptxas-options=-v
# Prepare extra compiler configuration
CUDA_INC      = $$join(INCLUDEPATH,' -I','-I',' ')
cuda.commands = $$CUDA_DIR/bin/nvcc -m64 -O3 -arch=$$CUDA_ARCH -c $$NVCCFLAGS \
                $$CUDA_INC $$LIBS  ${QMAKE_FILE_NAME} -o ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT} \
                2>&1 | sed -r \"s/\\(([0-9]+)\\)/:\\1/g\" 1>&2
cuda.dependency_type = TYPE_C
cuda.depend_command  = $$CUDA_DIR/bin/nvcc -O3 -M $$CUDA_INC $$NVCCFLAGS   ${QMAKE_FILE_NAME}

cuda.input = CUDA_SOURCES
cuda.output = ${OBJECTS_DIR}${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}_cuda.o
# Tell Qt that we want add more stuff to the Makefile
QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += cuda
```

Comment: Mac OS `sed` is not GNU `sed`. Try with `-E` instead?

Comment: That cleared that error up - I'm now getting the error: `:-1: error: file not found: @rpath/CUDA.framework/Versions/A/CUDA for architecture x86_64` despite running a 64bit system with CUDA64 bit

Comment: Seems to be a completely different issue.  I would point out that asking question this way ("my next problem is...") makes for very messy SO questions.  It's usually a good idea to post unrelated questions in *separate* SO questions.

Comment: Sorry Robert, I'll open a new question and remove the UPDATE - thankyou

Comment: If you or @ParkYoung-Bae want to provide an answer here, I would upvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Park Young-Bae suggested, Mac `sed` is not equivalent to `GNU sed` and therefore the flag:

```
2>&1 | sed -r \"s/\\(([0-9]+)\\)/:\\1/g\" 1>&2
```

had to be amended to:

```
2>&1 | sed -E \"s/\\(([0-9]+)\\)/:\\1/g\" 1>&2
```

This fixed the issue.